# General question regarding delta heding

Tags: finance, hedging, delta-hedging

I was wondering if I have to take the strike prices of options into consideration when doing a gamma and delta hedging.
As an example, let's suppose that I have 2 positions:

1. a long position call option with strike 55\$, delta $\Delta_1=0,5$ and Gamma $\Gamma_1=0,03$
2. a short position put option with strike 56\$, delta $\Delta_2=-0,7$ and Gamma $\Gamma_2=0,01$.

The difference in strike prices shouldn't play a role when doing gamma and delta hedging right?

Comment: That's right. The calculation of $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ already took the option's strike (and maturity, etc. etc.) into account.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't 100% sure but that cleared my doubts!